# Emberjs: Resolve form data from child views

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js

I have a OutputsFormView which should have a save and cancel handler for click events on the buttons. When the save button is clicked it should collect all values from the child views and send it to the controller which then persists it.

*outputs.js*

```
App.OutputsCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Output.createRecord();
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        return this.render('outputs/form', {
            controller: 'outputsCreate'
        });
    }
});

App.OutputsCreateController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    save: function(model) {
        // outputs empty values for title, receiver, value
        console.log(model);
    }
});

App.OutputsFormView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    classNames: ['form', 'form-horizontal'],

    save: function(e) {
        this.get('controller').send('save', {
            title: this.get('title'),
            receiver: this.get('receiver'),
            value: this.get('value')
        });
    },
    cancel: function(e) {

        console.log('canceling');
    }
});
```

*template*

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="outputs/form">
  {{#view App.OutputsFormView}}
    <legend class="text-right">create a new output</legend>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.title" placeholder="Lovely Afternoon Pizza"}}
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="receiver">Receiver</label>
        <div class="controls">
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.receiver" placeholder="The Goverment"}}
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="value">Receiver</label>
        <div class="controls">
          {{view App.ValueView valueBinding="view.value"}}
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="control-group pull-right">
        <div class="controls">
          <button type="button" {{action "save"}} class="btn">save</button>
          <button type="button" {{action "cancel"}} class="btn btn-red">cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

For some reason I cannot get the values of the child form views and unfortunately I have no idea what I have forgotten...

Bodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that each a valueBinding is available in the controller:

```
App.OutputsCreateController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    save: function(model) {
        var output = this.get('model');

        output.set('title', this.get('title'));
        output.set('receiver', this.get('receiver'));
        output.set('value', this.get('value'));

        output.save();
    }
});
```

This is better than resolving the values out of the view directly. But if you want to do this you can give your view a name:

```
{{view viewName="blabla"}}
```

and then access it through the parent view with:

```
this.get('blabla');
```

However I think the value binding method should be preferred